# Use a formula based on a table to determine which cells to format

Tags: excel

I have a table (called "MyTable") and I want to use conditional formatting to format *the entire row* of a table using a condition that is based on a column in that table.
Here's a little demo:
[image]
I want to format the whole row if Location = "London". I'm hoping I can use the "Use a formula to determine which cells to format" option of Conditional Formatting. Hence I selected all the cells in the table and tried to enter this formula: `=[@Location]="London"` but it didn't have the desired affect:

[image]

Is it possible to format an entire row based on some condition, if so, what is the formula for it?

Comment: Well, to apply the conditional formatting to an entire row you'd change to the "Applies to" entry to "=$3:$3" for row 3, etc. Are you trying to make the formatting dynamic? Will your table size be changing?

Comment: "Are you trying to make the formatting dynamic?" Depends what you mean by dynamic. If a person's location were to change then I want the formatting of the entire row to change. If that's what you mean by "dynamic" then the answer is "yes".
"Will your table size be changing?" Probably not in this case, but I always like to err on the side of caution and assume that it will.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't use structured references in conditional formatting.  You will need to refer to the cells in which the table is found.

Comment: @ScottCraner Could he implement a worksheet_change event to change the interior colors of the cells instead?

Comment: "Unfortunately you can't use structured references in conditional formatting. You will need to refer to the cells in which the table is found" Thanks Scott. That's very disappointing. Yet another feature of Excel that doesn't work well with tables (e.g. https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/304921-excel-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/16452913-get-tables-working-on-protected-sheets-add-rows)

Comment: @ScottCraner if you post your comment as an answer I shall mark it as so. thanks.

Comment: Found a work around

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use structured references directly in CF, but you can do a simple hack:

```
=INDIRECT("Table1[@Location]")="london"
```

[image]

Comment: I've frequently used INDIRECT() in Data Validation formulas so kicking myself for not thinking of this myself :) Thanks again.